# How to make the html5 audio tag work with iOS Safari

Tags: ios, html, ios7, safari

The audio tag on Safari does not seem to work...

Example:

http://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php

For me using iPhone 5s and iOS 7.1, the tag control says that the audio file cannot be played. Fix?

The code in the example above:

```
<audio controls src="data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAaaaaand so on" />
```

I need to use the data: method of providing the sound data in base64 format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OGG is not support on iOS.

As you can read in the [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1):

> Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports uncompressed WAV and
>   AIF audio, MP3 audio, and AAC-LC or HE-AAC audio. HE-AAC is the
>   preferred format.

Comment: Ok that's right. I was actually trying to use it with .m4a files (audio/mp4) which works in-app but it seems Safari doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, iOS Safari won't process base 64 encoded audio. No idea why, but you have to store it as an external file.

Comment: iOS 8 actually does. I know iOS 5 doesn’t (I have an iPad 1 here to test on), but I’m not sure when it gained this ability.